Should we remove the 'technology' tag?
technology isn't a meaningful tag. Shall we remove it?

By itself doesn't mean anything.
Unless someone comes up with editing the tag description in a way that it makes sense, it should be removed.
edit: removed it.

I recall that we removed the data tag a while back, but it ended up coming back. Is there something we can do to remove the tag permanently?

@NickODell I think moderators can do it, unless I'm mistaken
